# Distribution of $\int_0^t e^s dB(s)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider $$\left(\int_0^t e^s dB(s)\right)_{t\in [0,1]}$$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion.

What is the distribution of this process?

Since $f(s) = e^s$ is continuously differentiable, $B$ is process with uncorrelated increments and $\mathbb E [B(t)]\equiv 0$, one can use the fact that

$$\int_a^b f(s) dB(s) = f(b)B(b) - f(a)B(a) - \int_a^b B(s)f'(s) ds$$

This reduces in our specific case to

$$\int_0^t e^s dB(s) = e^t B(t) - \int_0^t B(s) s e^s ds$$

Now I am stuck to find the distribution of $\int_0^t B(s) s e^s ds$. Is there a convinient way to find its distribution or an easier way to find the distribution of the original process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
M_t=\int_0^ta(s)\,\mathrm dB(s)\qquad (M_t)_{t\geqslant0}\stackrel{\text{dist.}}{=}(B(A_t))_{t\geqslant0}\qquad A_t=\int_0^ta(s)^2\,\mathrm ds$$

Comment: I have a question about your answer. First I wanted to write an answer by myself, but I was faced with the problem: clearly every $M_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\int_0^te^{2s}ds)$. But how do you figure out the distribution for $t_0,\dots,t_k$ of $(M_{t_0},\dots,M_{t_k})$?

Comment: By what you say plus the fact that the increments of $M$ are independent since, for $s\leqslant t$, $M_t-M_s$ depends only on $(B_u-B_s)_{s\leqslant u\leqslant t}$ and that these families of Brownian increments are independent.

Comment: thanks, did not see the second point!

Comment: Does there need to be a restriction on the function $a(s)$ for this to hold true? How would you solve integrals of the form $\int_0^t B(s)a(s)ds$, just by reordering the equation written in my question?

Comment: Restriction: $a$ deterministic and locally square integrable. Reordering: indeed one can transform these into $\int AdB$ for $A_t=\int_0^ta(s)ds$.

Answer (score 1):

Call this process $M_t$.  By the [Dubins-Schwarz theorem](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/StoCal/sc3.pdf) (see page 54), your (*a-priori* local) martingale has the same distribution as a Brownian Motion evaluated at $[M]_t$ so it suffices to compute the quadratic variation of your process, which you can get from Ito's isometry.